# Tomcat servlet acting strange with json object

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, gson

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    LocationTypes locTypes = new LocationTypes();
    String json = gson.toJson(locTypes);

    out.print(json);
    out.flush();
}
```

If i take the above code, and System.out.println(json), it looks like this :

```
    {"locationTypes":["Hospital","Church","Restaurant","Bar","Other"]}
```

What i get in the browser, when pointing to the url for the servlet, i get this:

```
    {"calls":{"threadLocalHashCode":-2084311414},"typeTokenCache":{"com.google.gson.InstanceCreator\u003c?\u003e":{},"int":{},"java.lang.String":{},"java.lang.String[]":{},"java.util.Map\u003ccom.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken\u003c?\u003e, com.google.gson.TypeAdapter\u003c?\u003e\u003e":{},"java.util.List\u003ccom.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory\u003e":{},"java.lang.ThreadLocal\u003cjava.util.Map\u003ccom.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken\u003c?\u003e, com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter\u003c?\u003e\u003e\u003e":{},"com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory":{},"com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext":{},"com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken\u003c?\u003e":{},"java.util.Map\u003cjava.lang.reflect.Type, com.google.gson.InstanceCreator\u003c?\u003e\u003e":{},"com.google.gson.Gson":{},"boolean":{},"java.lang.reflect.Type":{},"data.LocationTypes":{},"java.lang.Class\u003c? super ?\u003e":{},"java.lang.Integer":{},"com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor":{},"com.google.gson.TypeAdapter\u003c?\u003e":{},"com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext":{}},"factories":[null,null,{"version":-1.0,"modifiers":136,"serializeInnerClasses":true,"requireExpose":false,"serializationStrategies":[],"deserializationStrategies":[]},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"constructorConstructor":{"instanceCreators":{}}},{"constructorConstructor":{"instanceCreators":{}},"complexMapKeySerialization":false},{"constructorConstructor":{"instanceCreators":{}},"fieldNamingPolicy":"IDENTITY","excluder":{"version":-1.0,"modifiers":136,"serializeInnerClasses":true,"requireExpose":false,"serializationStrategies":[],"deserializationStrategies":[]}}],"constructorConstructor":{"instanceCreators":{}},"serializeNulls":false,"htmlSafe":true,"generateNonExecutableJson":false,"prettyPrinting":false}
```

Comment: What does `LocationTypes` class look like?

Comment: Where do you set that locTypes is that JSON document? Can you give us all the code?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

I have reproduced your error. 
Unfortunately, you are passing the `gson` object to be converted to JSON.
Your problem is the result of a typo/mistake.

I ran the following code:

```
public static void main (String args[])
    {   
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          String json = gson.toJson(gson);
          System.out.println(json);
    }
```

And received the following:

```
{"calls":{"threadLocalHashCode":1253254570},"typeTokenCache":{"com.google.gson.Gson":{},"com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken\u003c?\u003e":{},"com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor":{},"com.google.gson.InstanceCreator\u003c?\u003e":{},"java.lang.reflect.Type":{},"boolean":{},"int":{},"com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext":{},"com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext":{},"java.lang.ThreadLocal\u003cjava.util.Map\u003ccom.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken\u003c?\u003e, com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter\u003c?\u003e\u003e\u003e":{},"java.util.List\u003ccom.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory\u003e":{},"java.util.Map\u003cjava.lang.reflect.Type, com.google.gson.InstanceCreator\u003c?\u003e\u003e":{},"com.google.gson.TypeAdapter\u003c?\u003e":{},"java.lang.Integer":{},"com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory":{},"java.lang.Class\u003c? super ?\u003e":{},"java.util.Map\u003ccom.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken\u003c?\u003e, com.google.gson.TypeAdapter\u003c?\u003e\u003e":{}},"factories":[null,null,{"version":-1.0,"modifiers":136,"serializeInnerClasses":true,"requireExpose":false,"serializationStrategies":[],"deserializationStrategies":[]},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"constructorConstructor":{"instanceCreators":{}}},{"constructorConstructor":{"instanceCreators":{}},"complexMapKeySerialization":false},{"constructorConstructor":{"instanceCreators":{}},"fieldNamingPolicy":"IDENTITY","excluder":{"version":-1.0,"modifiers":136,"serializeInnerClasses":true,"requireExpose":false,"serializationStrategies":[],"deserializationStrategies":[]}}],"constructorConstructor":{"instanceCreators":{}},"serializeNulls":false,"htmlSafe":true,"generateNonExecutableJson":false,"prettyPrinting":false}
```

Kudos to Pragmateek for also checking the GSON SVN repo.

### Original Answer

It's really quite impossible that `System.out.println(json);` would give you a different result than

```
out.print(json);
out.flush();
```

json is a String and dispays the same in any stream.

**Have you checked that you don't have a typo somewhere?** 
**I would suggest you copy and paste the code exactly as is within your project.**

In the browser, you are getting a JSON version of an object that has serialized all the object's values/fields to JSON.

Many of the keys within your generated JSON are actual fields of the object your trying to serialize to JSON as Pragmateek has said.

It could almost be suspected that your are passing your GSON object to be converted to JSON....

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    LocationTypes locTypes = new LocationTypes();
    String json = gson.toJson(locTypes);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    out.print(json);
    out.flush();
}
```

try setting content-type as above

Answer (score 0):

Is this the original code?

Are you sure there isn't a typo like:

```
out.print(gson);
```

Because the strange JSON really looks like a serialized GSON library object...

Comment: Don't be offended but allow me to insist: seems like your JSON is the exact JSON representation of this type: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java Sorry if I'm wrong, just ignore :)

Comment: I agree with Pragmateek. It feels like there is a typo/mistake in the given information. A string cannot output differently depending on the Stream. Seems like the OP is converting the GSON object to JSON ?

Comment: @Pragmateek He is converting his `GSON` object to `json`. It is essentially some typo which because of missing information was not visible.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't take much, a single letter. :)